# angularjs $index when ng-hide with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have itemlist which need to display with serial no. i used $index with ng-repeat but when element is hide at that time index was increased.

Code i tried as follow:

```
<div ng-repeat="itemRow in salesitem" class="tableRow h7" ng-hide="itemRow.flagDeleted">
                    <div class="tableCell">{{$index}}</div>
                    <div class="tableCell">{{itemRow.name}}</div>
                    <div class="tableCell">{{itemRow.qty}}</div>
</div>
```

when itemRow.flagDeleted is True at that item will not display but index will be increased so next item serial no is going wrong.

Comment: do filter the items before passing to ng-repeat as in `ng-repeat="itemRow in salesitem | filter : 'flagDeleted' : true"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead use a filter on the repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="itemRow in salesitem | filter:{ 'flagDeleted' : false}" class="tableRow h7">
    <div class="tableCell">{{$index}}</div>
    <div class="tableCell">{{itemRow.name}}</div>
    <div class="tableCell">{{itemRow.qty}}</div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/VfFcbUJpoXG6mRkJSFYS?p=preview

Comment: It will only work if objects have `flagDeleted: false` set explicitly. If they only have `flagDeleted: true` then it will not work (if `flagDeleted` is `undefined`). Better to implement custom filtering function.

Comment: @dfsq Can you please explain that more? I don't quite understand what you are saying. When I set all to true then no items show which is correct behaviour because the op wanted to hide all items with flagDeleted as true.

Comment: There can be no `flagDeleted: false` only `flagDeleted : true`. In this case `flagDeleted: false` will not match them http://plnkr.co/edit/nO14yZrpRkuCCBsw8nCE?p=preview

Comment: Oh. I understand what you are saying. I would think it would be normal for the flag to be set to either true or false and not for the property to be completely missing or set to some other value besides true or false